# UISEGMENTED CONTROL ui modification

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have attached my screen for your reference, what I have to do is I need to make the text inside the segmented control as visible which is bold. when I increase the size of the text inside the segment it increases but I need to increase the boldness of the text. 
I need the text color to be white and then text should be bod enough to identify. [image]

I have attached the customisation code for your reference

//Customising the segmented control with background color and tint color, font size

```
segmented_Control.tintColor = UIColor.white
segmented_Control.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 249/255, green: 8/255, blue: 129/255, alpha: 1)
segmented_Control.layer.cornerRadius = 20
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
segmented_Control.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: font],
                                             for: .normal)
```

Comment: Have you tried `UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)` ?

Comment: Not related to your question but remove the underscore "_' from the naming in `segmented_Control` it's really ugly un swift

Comment: ok zombie I will remove the underscore.

Comment: let me try @sandeep Bhandari

Comment: thanks @SandeepBhandari

Answer (score 0):

//Customising the segmented control with background color and tint color, font size

```
        segmented_Control.tintColor = UIColor(red: 249/255, green: 8/255, blue: 129/255, alpha: 1)
        segmented_Control.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        segmented_Control.layer.cornerRadius = 20
       // let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
        let font =  UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        segmented_Control.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: font],
                                             for: .normal)
```

now my code is working fine.